# for loop init variable scope between c++, java, C#

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, c++11

I have a problem in understanding the difference in scope of initial variable of for loop in those 4 languages C, C++, C#, Java

What I know is that in C#:  `for ( int i = 1; i<=5; i++)` here, `i` is a local variable dose not appear out the scope of the for brackets. So I can use it multiple times in multiple blocks, also Java is like that, but what I was know that c and c++ not the same as `i` in  `for ( int i = 1; i<=5; i++)` is declared on the level of for not in inside it.

I tried to run the below code to check if my thought correct or not:

old C:

```
   // old C:  error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode                                                                 
  // note: previous definition of 'i' was here 
    for ( int i = 0; i<=5; i++)  printf ("%d",i);
    for  ( int i = 5; i>=0; i--)  printf ("%d",i);
    printf ("%d",i);
```

C99:

```
    // error: 'i' undeclared (first use in this function) 
    for ( int i = 0; i<=5; i++)  printf ("%d",i);
    for  ( int i = 5; i>=0; i--)  printf ("%d",i);
    printf ("%d",i);
```

old C++:

```
    // error: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]                                                                  
    for ( int i = 0; i<=5; i++)  cout << i << endl;
    for( int i = 5; i>=0; i--)  cout << i << endl;
    cout << i;
```

C++11:

```
      for ( int i = 0; i<=5; i++)  cout << i << endl;
      for( int i = 5; i>=0; i--)  cout << i << endl;
      cout << i; error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
```

Java:

```
       for ( int i = 0; i<=5; i++)  System.out.println(i);
       for(  int i = 5; i>=0; i--)  System.out.println(i);
       System.out.println(i); // error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
```

C#:

```
    for ( int i = 0; i<=5; i++)  Console.Write(i); // 0 1 2 3 4 5 
    Console.WriteLine("");
    for ( int i = 5; i>=0; i--)  Console.Write(i); // 5 4 3 2 1 0
    Console.WriteLine(i); // error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
```

I think C99, C++11, C#, Java are same while the diffrence only in old C and C++.

Is this right or not ??

Thanks

Comment: Note your "old C++" is pre-standard "C++". This hasn't changed since the first standard. Basically, all behave the same, except that in C89 you can't declare `i` in the scope of the loop.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Do you mean you cannot declare inside the parenthesis or that it's scope will be that of the block the loop itself belongs to?

Comment: @Olaf i know that in C89 i can't initialize i inside the parenthesis, but my question is about the scope

Comment: @Marzouk: If you can't declare it inside the parentheses, then no scope is possible. In all the other languages, the scope is the complete `for` statement (that is, the test and advance expressions, and the body of the loop.)

Comment: @Olaf I mean in C89 you cannot declare inside the loop parenthesis. That makes the question of scope moot in this particular case.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You are right. But I do have in mind that one version of the standard did allow declaration/definition, but had the variable in the scope which contained the for loop. iirc, that was corrected with C99. I thought it was C89, but apparently not (I tried). So maybe it was C95? That I cannot test, as gcc does not support that standard. Do you have any pointer for me?

Comment: @Olaf Sorry, I am not sure about that. Maybe it was a pre-standard thing, like it was in C++.

Comment: ok, thanks all for your help. this really help me to achieve better understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite.

Only prestandard C++ (before the 1998 ANSI standard which became the ISO standard) behaves as you describe for "old C++".     That changed in draft standards in about 1995, from memory, and most compilers at that time adopted the change.    Before that, some C++ compilers limited scope of variables to loops as a vendor-specific extension.

C from the 1999 standard, standard C++, Java, and C# all limit scope of variables declared within a for loop to only that loop.

Standard C in 1989 (ANSI) and 1990 (ISO), prestandard C (including K&R), and prestandard C++ before 1995 do not.   As noted by juanchpanza in comments, C89/C90 does not permit variable declarations within loop initialisation at all.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what i need to know

Comment: Note that C89 does not allow variables declared the loop initialization as in OP's code.

Comment: True, juan.   I'll modify my post shortly to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is not right exactly for the pre-standart C++. Because some compilers have issue about loop variables which `i` can be used outside of the for loop block without redeclaration.  I mean

```
// error: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]                                                                  
for ( int i = 0; i<=5; i++)  cout << i << endl;
for( int i = 5; i>=0; i--)  cout << i << endl;
cout << i;
```

This may not be error in that compiler. And you may see this macro in files to protection.

```
#define for if(0) {} else for
```

After that now `i` is in else block.

Comment: Redefining language keywords, as in that macro, gives undefined behaviour in both C and C++.    Although it often gives the "protection" you describe with real-world compilers/preprocessors, that is not actually guaranteed.